# HTML is not being indented

Tags: indentation

I have just created a file `.html`. When I run `set filetype?` I get `filetype=html`. Then I select this code:

```
<div>
<span>
</span>
</div>
```

and press `=` but the code is not indented... I don't have problems to indent `php` files for example using the same procedure.

Comment: Make sure you have set `:filetype plugin indent on` The indent part is important

Comment: What's the output of `:scriptnames` after you open an HTML file?

Answer (score 3):

I tried your sample (result below), so vim's html autoformat/indent definitely works with this.

```
<div>
    <span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here's the steps to do it:

```
:filetype plugin indent on " enable the filetype indent plugin
:e                         " re-open the file (very important!)
:scriptnames               " make sure you see an ".../indent/html.vim"
:=G                        " or whatever range you want
```

`scriptnames` is the key to identifying whether the `indent/html.vim` is properly loaded. If not, then you probably need to re-open the file.

Note that if you put `filetype plugin indent on` in the `~/.vimrc`, then you won't need to re-open the file since that plugin was already enabled before you opened the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the options mentioned in `:help =`:

```
={motion}   Filter {motion} lines through the external program
            given with the 'equalprg' option.  When the 'equalprg'
            option is empty (this is the default), use the
            internal formatting function |C-indenting| and
            |'lisp'|.  But when 'indentexpr' is not empty, it will
            be used instead |indent-expression|.  When Vim was
            compiled without internal formatting then the "indent"
            program is used as a last resort.
```

If it is working in php files, try comparing the values of the relevant options in each of them.

Your example works fine here, and the command `:4verbose setlocal equalprg indentexpr` prints the following:

```
  equalprg=
  indentexpr=HtmlIndent()
    Last set from /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/indent/html.vim
```

Comment: what I get from `4verbose setlocal equalprg indentexpr` is this: `equalprg= indentexpr=`